# spring-cloud-contract framework and contractverifier tests execution

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am a newbie to spring-cloud-contract. As per the document, I have developed contracts and after `gradle clean build` command execution, test cases are created under `build\generated-test-sources\com\springframework\cloud\contract\verifier\tests\ContractVerifierTest.java`. when I do `gradle clean build`, cloud-contract starts a http server on default port and execute these test cases or it runs on JVM? Is there way to execute these testcases standalone ( i mean out of gradle build)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand properly what you ask for but I'm assuming that you want to run the tests against sth else than mockmvc (which is not binding to a port btw). You can read this section of the docs to see how to use the explicit node to send a real request to an app bound to a port http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_working_with_context_paths. Also as a newbie you should read the whole documentation of spring cloud contract.